# best way to have a shopping cart modal's header match with the body?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to align the header of my shopping cart modal with the items that the user adds.
What I'm trying to fix: [image]

I need the name to align with roses, description to align with description etc... each to their respective column. What is the best way around that?
My code:

App.js:

```
import ShoppingCart from "./ShoppingCart";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ShoppingCart />
    </div>
  );
}
```

ShoppingCart.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./ShoppingCart.css";
import CartItem from "./CartItem";

const ShoppingCart = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="shopping-cart-modal">
      <div className="shopping-cart-modal-content">
        <div className="shopping-cart-modal-header">
          <p>Name</p>
          <p>Description</p>
          <p>Price</p>
        </div>
        <div className="shopping-cart-modal-body">
          <CartItem />
        </div>
        <div className="shopping-cart-modal-footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShoppingCart;
```

CartItem.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./CartItem.css";

const CartItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="cart-item">
      <p>Roses</p>
      <p>Beautiful hand picked roses fresh out of our gardins</p>
      <p>$ 9.99</p>
      <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartItem;
```

ShoppingCart.css:

```
.shopping-cart-modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.shopping-cart-modal-content {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.shopping-cart-modal-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
```

CartItem.css :

```
.cart-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: baseline;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-meadow-ntwqf?file=/src/CartItem.css

Comment: Why not use a table?

Comment: Well you are using `display:flex` and `justify-content: space-evenly` with three items in the header and four items in the cart-items, they will always be offset. Perhaps placing then in a grid or moving your button out of the cart-items?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using flexbox for so long I completely forgot about css grid. I would like to thank the comments for pulling my attention towards it.